# Finding how much the sample mean differs from true mean

Tags: probability

I have a textbook problem that gives a true mean of 50 months, and variance of 2500. The problem asks to find the probability that the sample mean is within one month of the true mean, where the sample size is 25.
Using the formula $Q(\frac{X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}})$

It seems to me that the answer should be $Q(\frac{49 - 50}{\frac{50}{\sqrt{25}}})-Q(\frac{51 - 50}{\frac{50}{\sqrt{25}}})$

but the published answer is just $Q(\frac{49 - 50}{\frac{50}{\sqrt{25}}})$.

Have I misunderstood something basic here? The distribution here is an exponential. Thanks.

Comment: What is the word for word exercise ?

Comment: Your result is negative.

Comment: Callculus, my result reduces to 1 - 2*Q(.1), which is positive. Having found additional mistakes in the published textbook answers, I'm going to assume this one is as well.

Comment: It is the other way round. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate $P(-0.1\leq Z\leq 0.1)$. This is $\Phi(0.1)-\Phi(-0.1)\quad $.

The (standard) normal distribution is symmetric. Therefore $\Phi(-0.1)=1-\Phi(0.1)$

We can replace $\Phi(-0.1)$ by $1-\Phi(0.1)$. This results in

$P(-0.1\leq Z\leq 0.1)=\Phi(0.1)-(1-\Phi(0.1))=2\Phi(0.1)-1$

In general it is

$P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=2\Phi(z)-1$

And using the  [Q-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) instead it becomes

$P(-z\leq Z\leq z)=2(1-\text Q(z))-1=1-2Q(z)$

Comment: OK. so you have restated with the erf function what I did with Marcum's Q function. Thanks for confirming the book is in error.

Comment: I really thought that you meant the standard normal distribution. But with the Q-function your comment above is right. I included the Q-function into my answer.